# Installed Software/Plugins On Eclipse Has Stopped Working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Indigo) and have been using it for several months.
I had many installed plugins including a SVN one and e-git.

Then one day, they just all stopped working. For example, I used to be able to commit from the Explorer (using the SVN plugin), but that option has disappeared as if it is not installed.

I have checked the installed software list and they are all present.

Is there a setting somewhere that I may have miss?

Thanks in adavnced!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the error log in workspace/.metadata/.log to see if there is any warnings or errors.

Also, have you tried other perspectives, like plug-in development, or SVN.

Comment: I was always able to do this from the PHP perspective. There is a git perspective, but like I said, I used to be able to do it from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse
Go to Window -> Show view -> Other -> SVN

Choose new workspace and check out the project that you did